# Delphi FDQuery Fieldbyname conversion error

Tags: delphi

I have defined a MySQL database with a table that includes a field of type `varchar(128)`, I call it `fieldinquestion`. I use a query to access this field, which usually works nicely. However, when I assign a string to the field, I get an error that I don't understand.

```
try
   Self.FDQuery1.FieldByName('fieldinquestion').AsString:='Hello There';    //or something similar.
except
    ---> error: 'Could not convert variant of type (String) into type (Double)'
    aDataType:=Self.FDQuery1.FieldByName(GCssValidationDisplay).DataType;  --datatype is ftString
end;
```

In the `try..except` clause, this causes an error, but a verification for the datatype shows it is a string!

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of SQL is assigned to `FDQuery1` that the time you are trying to assign a value to `fieldinquestion`? You don't usually assign field values via a Query component, unless you are using an `UPDATE` statement, in which case using `FieldByName(...).AsXXX` is the wrong way to go to begin with. Please provide a [mcve] of what you are trying too accomplish.

Comment: Where are you verifying the datatype, on the server or in the FDQuery?  I ask because the only way I can think of that might produce the error (apart from a memory overwrite in your app) is if the server table is corrupt.  So when you supply the requested MRE, please include the DDL SQL to create the table your FDQuery is accessing and get your MRE code to operate on that.

Comment: thank you all -- i verify the datatype right in the line following the error with aDataType:=Self... it's a ftString.